# Field Calculator: extract single cell based on it's OBJECTID?

Tags: field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-pro, objectid

Is it possible to copy a single value inside a field based on it's OBJECTID from another field?

Some sort of if-then-else logic?

For example I would like to copy the value in the Area field corresponding to OBJECTID 3. And to have it in the first row in the Level field with the rest of it's rows remaining to 'Null'.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 1.4 with Python 3.5.

[image: Field Calculator]

[image: target values]

Comment: Don't believe a look-ahead can be done inside a single field calc expression without some hackery (you could embed a search cursor in the codeblock, for example -- seriously, don't do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this - quick code in the Python pane or a cursor in the field calculator are two options I'd look at.

1. **Python pane:**
   In the ArcGIS Pro Python pane you can enter the following code to lookup the `Area` value against a specified ObjectID, and copy that value into the `Level` field on another specific ObjectID.  (`"testPoints"` is the name of the layer I tested on)

   ```py
   lookupDict = {1:3, 9:24}
   areaDict = dict()
   fields = ['OID@', 'Area', 'Level']

   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("testPoints", fields) as cursor:
       for row in cursor:
           areaDict[row[0]] = row[1]

   with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("testPoints", fields) as uCursor:
       for uRow in uCursor:
           if uRow[0] in lookupDict:
               if uRow[0] in areaDict:
                   myval = areaDict[lookupDict[uRow[0]]]
                   uRow[2] = myval
                   uCursor.updateRow(uRow)
   ```

   [image]

   The result in the Attribute Table (sometimes you need to close and reopen the table to see the changes):

   [image]
2. **Field Calculator:**
   You can use python inside the field calculator reasonably easily (and ArcGIS Pro help pages include [examples](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field-examples.htm) doing this)

   Here I've used a python dictionary to store the ObjectID I wish to update, and the ObjectID I am looking up.  From your question you want to get the `Area` value from ObjectID `3` and put it into the `Level` field for ObjectID `1`.  I have included `9: 24` for example if you wish to use more lookups in the same calculation.

   Expression (on Level field):

   ```py
   lu(!ObjectID!)
   ```

   and code-block:

   ```py
   def lu(oid):
       lookupDict = {1: 3, 9: 24}
       myval = None
       if oid in lookupDict:
           with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("testPoints", ['OID@', 'Area']) as cursor:
               for row in cursor:
                   if row[0] == lookupDict[oid]:
                       myval = row[1]
                       break
       return myval
   ```

   [image]

   And the result in the Attribute table:

   [image]

   Depending on the size of your table, you may wish to process the Field Calculator Search Cursor separately (like the python pane example) so you're not running the search cursor on every update cursor row.

Comment: This is really awesome @Midavalo. I couldn't find any info regarding this topic, I hope it will be of use to everybody